# Finding the n th term in Fibonacci series

Tags: python, performance, fibonacci-sequence

Solving a problem in coding contest I came across a problem, which on digging a bit lead me to the data set in [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/147456/finding-the-equation-of-curve) . Since the program to enumerate and finding the solution was too complex and execution time was below par I jot down the logic to the equation of curve (a single line)

Upon further digging deep I found that I missed the series which was forming a Fibonacci Series, hence by Binet's fourmla I found the nth term of the series which was even efficient. Here is the code

```
import math
import sys

def powLF(n):
    if n == 1:     return (1, 1)
    L, F = powLF(n//2)
    L, F = (L**2 + 5*F**2) >> 1, L*F
    if n & 1:
        return ((L + 5*F)>>1, (L + F) >>1)
    else:
        return (L, F)

def fib(n):
    if n & 1:
        return powLF(n)[1]
    else:
        L, F = powLF(n // 2)
        return L * F

def sum_digits(n):
   r = 0
   while n:
       r, n = r + n % 10, n // 10
   return r

def _print(string):
    fo = open("output.txt", "w+")
    fo.write(string)
    fo.close()

try:
    f = open('input.txt')
except IOError:
    _print("error")
    sys.exit()
num = f.readline()
try:
   val = int(num)
except ValueError:
    _print("error")
    sys.exit()

sum = sum_digits(int(num))
f.close()

if (sum == 2):
    _print("1")
else:
    _print(str(int(math.ceil(fib(sum)))))
```

Although still the code doesn't seem to match the par criteria, how can I optimize the code further ?

Comment: Does the code work as required?  You say it throws an exception - you should probably do something about that before this code is ready for review.  You could either avoid it by rejecting out-of-range inputs, or fix your code to handle larger values.

Comment: Code works as required for smaller integers but for integers greater than 4 digits it throws exception.

Comment: The code looks fine to me apart from the fact that it can throw an exception. The function `fib()``powLF()` are giving you complexity of `log(n)` plus the execution time of the function `sum_digits()` is 479 ns per loop which is perfectly fine.

Comment: @Milind Answers should go in answers, not comments.

Comment: I am still getting my solution rated as `poor` and I cannot understand why ! @Peilonrayz @Milind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code looks fine to me apart from the fact that it can throw an exception. The function `fib() powLF()` are giving you the complexity of `O(log(n))` plus the execution time of the function sum_digits() is 479 ns per loop which is perfectly fine.

```
> %timeit sum_digits(n)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 479 ns per loop
```

Take a look at Lecture 3 of the [MIT Open Courseware](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-046j-introduction-to-algorithms-sma-5503-fall-2005/video-lectures/lecture-3-divide-and-conquer-strassen-fibonacci-polynomial-multiplication/) course on algorithms for a good analysis of the matrix approach.

```
>>> timeit.timeit('fib(1000)', 'from __main__ import fibM as fib', number=10000)
0.40711593627929688
>>> timeit.timeit('fib(1000)', 'from __main__ import fibL as fib', number=10000)
0.20211100578308105
```

Answer (score -2):

This is not fibonacci series.  It's also recursively calculating the result which is almost certainly a bad idea if performance is at all important.  For calculating fibonacci, it would be better to use some sort of list, for example:

```
def fib(n):
    f = [0,1,1]
    for i in xrange(3,n):
        f.append(f[i-1] + f[i-2])
    return 'The %.0fth fibonacci number is: %.0f' % (n,f[-1])
```

If continued calls were to be made, then you should consider saving f and calculating only what is required to arrive at *n*.

Comment: This is certainly not the correct solution, the code does not need to store the series, the series can extend up to very large `n`, also he needs to find the nth term not, according to ti this, he will need to find all the terms.